# SQLite error no such table: activitypointer in resco field service mobile app

Tags: mobile, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

Whilst we are trying to add task, phone call or opportunity which are belonged to activitypointer entity in offline mode in resco field service mobile app the error we are getting like:

```
SQLite error
no such table: activitypointer
Failed cmd: SELECT [activitypointer].[subject] ,[activitypointer].[scheduledstart] ,[activitypointer].[scheduledend] ,[activitypointer].[prioritycode] ,[activitypointer].[description] ,[activitypointer].[activitytypecode] ,[activitypointer].[activityid]   FROM [activi...
```

it seems that we have enabled online & offline enabled for this entity like other entities work but not sure why it doesn't work where other entities work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the error and got reply from resco team like below:

This is not possible to fetch this table in online mode, since this is virtual table for internal use for resco.

You can set the explicit fetch for online mode using executeOffline
https://www.resco.net/javascript-bridge-reference/#MobileCRM_FetchXml_Fetch_executeOffline

But in the case when you know what type of activity you need to retrieve, try to create exact fetch for specific entity.